# Can I win in Unikong?

Tags: unikong

Every three levels it says that I have won (after I unlock the chest), but can I actually win or does the game have an infinite number of levels?

Comment: You can brag about your reputation!

Comment: @Mathias711 i have way more reputation in the game than i do in real life. it's kind of sad if you think about it

Comment: It is way easier there, unfortunately

Comment: I got to 5120 :( I have more in real stack. btw what is this "life" thing everyone is talking about?

Comment: What if the aim of the game is to reach actual Jon Skeet's rep? I mean, woah.

Comment: @ardaozkal I dunno.  I think somebody said it is 42?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There seems to be an infinite amount of levels, with the difficulty getting harder and harder every time. There seems to be 3 different levels:

- **1st level**

  - Unicorn
  - No trolls
  - No blaster
- **2nd level**

  - Unicorn
  - Trolls
  - Blaster
- **3rd level**

  - Unicorn
  - Trolls
  - Blaster
  - Key + Treasure chest (key drops once all mod diamonds are collected)

whose layouts are exactly the same every 3 levels, however various factors noted by [Haney in the comments below](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/260965/can-i-win-in-unikong/260969#comment363921_260969) affect the game as you progress further and further:

- Trolls move faster and faster
- Downvotes are thrown more often
- Downvotes fall faster
- Unicorn targets you, with greater and greater reliability

So no, there's no way you can win at the game; it's a battle of how long you'll last with your health versus the ever increasing challenges thrown at you, since once you run out of health it's all "wump wump" and game over.

Comment: Actually, there are more difficulty changes every 3 levels...

Comment: @Haney Could you elaborate on this? Do the trolls move faster?

Comment: @skully i think he is talking about the fact that there isnt trolls on the first of the 3 levels. though there may be more differences

Comment: The trolls move faster, the downvotes are thrown more often, they fall faster, the unicorn also targets you (changes direction to head towards you) more reliably!

Comment: I think the key drops when you collect all mod diamonds. Also, level 11 doesn't seem to be humanly beatable.

Comment: @ninjalj tough, but not impossible. having played quite a bit of bullet hell games it's not that tough, but the wonky controls make it a tad frustrating

Comment: @skully now i wanna try it out too but they took it off. is there another site i can play it on?